# I was refused a UK visa because of my visit history

Tags: visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, standard-visitor-visas

[image][image]

I plan to attach my 2014 and 2015 annual leave letters to prove I was on leave, and a letter from my sales manager who was in charge of the business during my vacation.

I intend to explain all my sources of income in additional letter because the ECO calculations of my income were different from mine.

How else can I improve my new application?

Comment: It's still pretty easy to read the words you scribbled out.  It's better to use an image editor to draw black boxes over them.

Comment: You also want a good explanation why you stayed one month on the first occasion after requesting 5 days. In my thinking, your current income and the explanation for discrepancy in previous request vs. time spent will be the major issues to address.

Comment: Well,there was change in circumstances, my 2014 annual leave was granted 21december 2014 which lasted 30January 2015., cos my holiday was long i decided to enjoy it and left.on 17th January. Secondly cos d visa was multiple visa entry and it was valid,dats why i embarked on my 2015 annual leave which commenced April 15 and lasted May 30..My employment was properly mamaged cos my duties were covered for me during my vacation which was arranged by Head of department. My business manager was in charge of my business too.

Comment: If you had a month of leave, why did you say you would be staying for five days?

Comment: Yea,am trying to reapply and put more evidence and explanation. E.g my approved leave letter in year 2014 and 2015,letter from my sale's manager who managed the business.

Comment: Yea,like i said there is change in circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

They got you on V 4.2 (a) and (e).  Starting with (e)...

> (e) must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in
>   relation to their visit without working or accessing public funds.
>   This includes the cost of the return or onward journey, any costs
>   relating to dependants, and the cost of planned activities such as
>   private medical treatment.

The ECO went through your financial evidence and determined that you did not have the capacity for a visit to the UK because you are apparently making less than GBP 150 per month (118+25 = 143).  You believe that the ECO got the exchange rates wrong and that your income is really about GBP 365 per month. If you can substantiate this income and explain how the error occurred with neutral language, your position will be *marginally* improved.

And for V 4.2 (a)...

> (a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit;

In a previous application you told them you would be staying for about a week and this was proportionate to your job situation and your financial capacity so they issued the visa. You then stayed for a long time, Presumably you were not accommodated for free and even with the most generous calculations a two month visit to the UK should consume close to a year's salary for you.  Had you disclosed your agenda in your application they would have refused because your outlay is disproportionate to your means.

You propose to rebut the ECO's findings by including a statement showing your holiday entitlement and a 'change of circumstances'. You wrote...

> Well,there was change in circumstances, my 2014 annual leave was
>   granted 21december 2014 which lasted 30January 2015., cos my holiday
>   was long i decided to enjoy it and left.on 17th January.

You expect to tell the ECO that you applied for a 5 day trip and had no clue that you had holiday banked. Your holiday dropped from the blue with no prior notice on 21 Dec 2014.  This is going to be a terribly awkward explanation and they will not buy it because people who are planning international travel will often know how much holiday they have banked. Naive strategy.   The ECO will most likely conclude that you painted them a picture of a short visit in order to qualify and then exploited the opportunity.

So returning to V 4.2 (a), it's likely the ECO concluded that you were actually looking for work in the UK during those 2 months and had you found work (illegal work by the way), you would not have returned to your home country.

So you have a credibility problem on two fronts, and your plan is...

> I intend to attach my 2o14 and 2015 annual leave letter to prove i was
>   on leave, a letter from my sales manager who was in charge of the
>   business during my vacation. I intend to explain all my sources of
>   income in additional lettrr cos the eco didnt sum my income up the way
>   i did

Given that the performance on your last visit was poor and your finances are marginal and that you will be representing yourself I would expect them to use the discrepancy method to generate another refusal.  Accordingly you will need to considerably improve your evidence and to think up a compellingly sound reason for your performance shortfall.  It needs to be more convincing than citing a "change in circumstances" and "...I decided to enjoy myself..." because how did you support yourself and where did the money come from?

> Any other suggestions will be appreciated.

My suggestion is to build up a record of performance in the affluent Commonwealth and countries like the USA and Brazil before attempting to apply for a UK entry clearance again.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Regarding the income issue, the ECO has indeed misplaced a decimal point - the letter shows a conversion of 100,000 NGN to £25.32, while xe.com shows it as £252.57.

Comment: What would traveling to Brazil improve his chances?

Comment: @QuoraFeans it would show he abides by the conditions of his visa. There's no other way to prove this because he will not a new UK visa for a long time without showing significant change in circumstances.

Comment: @chx: I totally understand that an experienced international traveler who plays by the rules will have a better chance of getting a visa. However, why Brazil? Are Nigerians regarded potential illegal immigrant in Brazil? It obviously makes sense that if he was in the US (or Australia, New Zealand) legally and left the country he does not have much interest in immigrating illegally into the UK.

Comment: @QuoraFeans there is nothing in the Brazil/Nigeria economies that suggest a unique pull factor. Instead it's that Brazil has a tightly controlled and sophisticated regime and ECO's like to see things like that. It adds immeasurable credibility to an applicant's intent.