# If I stayed longer than stated on my UK visa application, would that affect my next application?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I visited the UK last year for two months. On my application, I stated that i was only going to visit for two weeks but I stayed longer than that, but I did not overstay. I read online that this may be grounds for refusal on my next application. Is this true? I would appreciate some clarification on this topic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes** this is true. See a [somewhat similar situation here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87932/i-was-refused-a-uk-visa-because-of-my-visit-history/87937#comment208479_87937) although in his case he had a couple additional complications from taking too much leave/vacation time in the consular officers opinion.

It is not an absolute deal breaker however be prepared to explain why two weeks became two months, especially if you're a worker (two months is a lot of vacation for many countries) or a student whose school was not on vacation over that two month period.

Read this site on do's and don'ts and [**hidden requirements**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/hidden-requirements-in-uk-visa-applications-source-of-evidence-of-funds) and problems like [**provenance of fund**s, **funds parking**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking) etc to avoid making any of those mistakes.

Comment: Also, be prepared to explain how you supported yourself during the longer trip. They may suspect illegal work in the UK.

Comment: I was there as a tourist, not a worker nor a student.I have over 100,000 dollars in my bank account. I'm married with a 9 year old I own a few apartments, land, new car, own my own business etc. I'm just on the fence on whether or not i should apply again

Comment: @AshieAshh  It doesn't matter how much money you have in your bank account, don't take it personally. Much wealthier people have been refused UK visas for the flimsiest of reasons.

Comment: @SheikPaul  I understand i was just replying to the "they may suspect illegal work" and i do realize that they refuse people for the flimsiest of reason no matter who you are or else i wouldn't be worried lol. Do you have any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: There is no magic bullet. See my revised answer for some pointers. Admin doesn't like us continuing a long series of comments outside the main answer.