# Can you travel one day before a visa becomes valid, and leave three weeks after it expires?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, visa-expiration

My mum's visa is valid on the 23rd November and she will be leaving Fiji on the 22nd November and arrive UK on the 23rd November.

1) Is she allowed to travel from Fiji on the 22nd since the visa is not yet valid?

The expiry date is 23rd May but the return flight was booked after 19 days the expiry date.

2) Can she leave the UK 19 days after the expiry date?

Comment: What do you think _Expiry Date_ means if it had no meaning and she could ignore it??

Comment: @Aganju the confusion is understandable. For example for the US you can ignore it.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Yes, the US gives _Entry Visa_, and _expired_ means only that you can no longer use it to enter.

Comment: I wouldn't know for the UK, but normally it might (should?) be possible to extend the expiry date rather easily. Done that a couple of times. Though of course it would be best _not_ to show them a return ticket that was already dated late, which indicates willful intent... that surely wouldn't go well.

Comment: There's another issue here that her planned stay seems to be more than 6 months, when the UK usually only lets people in as visitors for up to 6 months.

Comment: @Damon It sounds as if the visa is 6 month standard visitor visa. Extending it is impossible.

Answer (score 12):

> Can she leave the UK 19 days after the expiry date?

That is definitely a **No No** for the U.K.

You have to leave the UK on or before the expiry date of your visa. Or in case you have a long term visa you have to leave within the period given to you when you were admitted to the UK, even if your visa lasts beyond that date.

> Is she allowed to travel from Fiji on the 22nd since the visa is not yet valid?

Depends upon the airline. There is no well known hard and fast policy for this.

With this ticket she might be refused entry. Even if they don’t ask her about the return ticket, she will mention the duration on the landing card.

This ticket will need to be changed and while you’re changing it also change the outbound leg for peace of mind.

A very important note by  @Zach Lipton:

> She should only stay six months in the UK if that's what she said she would do on her visa application. If she said she would stay for a shorter time, [she could be refused entry or refused a visa in the future](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125739/for-how-long-can-i-stay-in-the-uk-if-iam-on-a-6-month-visit-visa) if she suddenly extends her stay to six months when she said she wouldn't be there that long.

Comment: What happens if she attempts to leave after the expiry date? Will she be deported?

Comment: @Strawberry the UK haven't generally run their own exit controls , preferring to collect information from the transport companies (this may be changing soonish though). Further, deportation is expensive and pointless when the subject is trying to leave anyway. So it's reasonably likely she would leave without hassle. The big problem comes when trying to get another UK visa, or to enter a country with which the UK chooses to share the information.

Comment: The airline will use the arrival date for figuring the validity of the visa.

Comment: Nope it’s not that simple.