# UK visa refused due to length of previous stay (paragraph 4.2) - what to do?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens

[image: refusal letter]

That was thw refusal letter i got .. been traveling to the uk since 2011 and all through my travel history have never stayed this long.. i own my company an i stayed dis long cause of marital issues.. came bach home as soon as everything was ok. pls house kindly advice on what to do. thanks in anticipation

Comment: Your explanation does not make sense and will not make sense to any Entry Clearance Officer. You overstayed because of marital issues? Because of marital issues you could not return anywhere in Nigeria? Were you in fear of your life? I will not advice you to provide such an excuse in your subsequent application.

Comment: Thank you @cHiEfImmigrationvIoLaTer.. what possible excuse can  i give then? am just been honest.!!. my wife and i had some issues 2017 and i was psychological depressed.went for  my regular check up and my doctor advised me i take time off work and rest cause of my high blood pressure and work stress..

Comment: Thank you @cHiEfImmigrationvIoLaTer.. what possible excuse can  i give then? am just been honest.!!. my wife and i had some issues 2017 and i was psychological depressed.went for  my regular check up and my doctor advised me i take time off work and rest cause of my high blood pressure and work stress..just decided to stay back for 5 month to rest. and allow the issue between me and my wife to settle down . my business was going fine while i was in the uk! my manager and other member of staff took care of my business and my phone and email were open for me to be reached.. pls advice!

Answer (score 2):

Going from 2 weeks to 5 months is a material change - had you requested such a long stay in your application your visit visa may not have been approved. There are other examples of this on TSE eg [I was refused a UK visa because of my visit history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87932/i-was-refused-a-uk-visa-because-of-my-visit-history) and [Cancelled UK visa on entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry)

Advice on what to do is simple: If you reapply, you will have to address the refusal reasons given in the decision by providing a convincing explanation and supporting evidence where possible.

Comment: He will have to address the refusal basis in convincing fashion. So far he has not provided any convincing explanation.

Comment: i applied and got the visa 2015. couldn't travel cause of work commitments.. decided to travel 2017 during which i had a marital issue couple with my health condition.. pls what possible excuse can i give.. lost in thought........

Comment: @richard Is your wife in the UK? Do your bank statements and tax returns and your company trading accounts support your assertions regarding how you met your expenses and family commitments while you were in the UK? If I were the ECO I’d expect to see evidence eg funds being transferred to your personal account from your business account, payments to your family in Nigeria, withdrawals in the UK to show how you covered your expenses and allay any suspicion that you worked illegally. It may we’ll be best to get advice from an Immigration lawyer before you attempt to reapply

Comment: Can you provide the kind of evidence Traveller is suggesting? If not forget it. Sorry that I don’t have good news.

Comment: thank you for your taking your time to comment..before i left Nigeria i had a PTA of $2600 which i bought from travelex.i have the teller stamped on my passport. I knew i was gong to the uk to rest so i made plans for it already and i was staying at my cousin's all thru my stay.. my wife has a beauty shop so she really didn't need much support from me even tho i left some money in her account to support the family.Do i neeed to go to my bank and print  my bank statement to proof that? and is my PTA enough proof i had money on me to cover my stay.?